# How to crate multiple lists from another list based on condition/breakpoints in Python?

Tags: python, python-3.x, list

I'm looking for a way to create multiple lists from one large list.

What I want to do is to filter out different digit groups (amounts of fruits sold each week) form a list. Each group of digits should be in a separate list when it hits '******' string that indicates where each group should end.

```
Example list:

['apples', '1000', '2000', '2500', '******', 'oranges', '5000', '150', '******']
```

So far I've got this:

```
list = []
for i in mainList:
        if i.isdigit():
            list.append(i)
    print(list)
```

However, my code prints everything in one list like that:

```
#Ouput = ['1000', '2000', '2500', '5000', '150']
```

How can divide the output into separate lists so that each fruit group is printed in a separate "blocks" and all of them are part of a larger list?

The result I'm looking for should look like this:

```
[['1000', '2000', '2500'], ['5000', '150']]
```

So far I've tried this:

```
for i in mainList:
   if '******' in i:
       break
   if i != '******':
       result.append(i)
```

But this returns the same list and I was expecting it to break the loop at the first `'******'` breakpoint. I am struggling to separate each part of the list after the `'******'` delimiter.

I'd appreciate any help I can get.

Comment: Are you open to a dictionary keyed by the fruit name?

Comment: No, I'm supposed to use loops for that.

Answer (score 6):

The most *pythonic* way I can think of is to use [itertools.groupby](https://docs.python.org/3/library/itertools.html#itertools.groupby):

```
from itertools import  groupby

lst = ['apples', '1000', '2000', '2500', '******', 'oranges', '5000', '150', '******']

result = [list(group) for k, group in  groupby(lst, key=str.isdigit) if k]
print(result)
```

**Output**

```
[['1000', '2000', '2500'], ['5000', '150']]
```

As an alternative you could use a for loop:

```
result = []
start = True
for element in lst:
    if start and element.isdigit():  # start group
        result.append([element])
        start = False
    elif element.isdigit():  # just append to current group
        result[-1].append(element)
    else:  # close group
        start = True

print(result)
```

**Output**

```
[['1000', '2000', '2500'], ['5000', '150']]
```

Answer (score 1):

If you want to use `for` loops, this will work, if it is guaranteed that the list will have the proper format.

```
mylist = ['apples', '1000', '2000', '2500', '******', 'oranges', '5000', '150', '******']
terminator = '******'

result = []
sublist = []
for item in mylist:
    if item == terminator:
        result.append(sublist)
        sublist = []
    elif item.isdigit():
        sublist.append(item)

print(result)
```

The printout from that is what you wanted:

```
[['1000', '2000', '2500'], ['5000', '150']]
```

Comment: OP is skipping the fruit names in their example.

Comment: I'm looking to extract just the digits. Like this: [['1000', '2000', '2500'], ['5000', '150']]

Comment: I have edited the answer, so only the digits remain now.

Answer (score 1):

Well, try this:

```
mylst = ['apples', '1000', '2000', '2500', '******', 'oranges', '5000', '150', '******']

finallst = []
digits = []

for i in mylst:
  if i.isdigit():
    digits.append(i)
  else:
    digits = []
  if digits not in finallst and digits:
    finallst.append(digits)

print(finallst)
```

What I am doing there is:

- Taking a temporary list to store the digits in it.
- Taking the final list and appending the existing list of digits to
  it.
- Once I find the list element which is not int, I empty the list so
  that we can reuse it with next elements.